# How can i load a session without refresing a whole div inside which the session is stored?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

```
<div class="row" id="getsum">
    <?php $i=0;$j=0;  
    $sum=Session::get('sumofac');
    // dd($sum);
    echo 'sum= '.$sum; 

    foreach(@$vehicles as $vehicle_details) {$i++; if($vehicle_details->is_airport_trips == 1 && $vehicle_details->is_private_airport==1 ) { 
      echo ' inside private ';
      ?>
    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 @if($vehicle_details->is_shared_airport) shared_airport_yes @endif 
    @if($vehicle_details->is_private_airport) <?php $j++;?> private_airport_yes @endif">
    <div class="shared_airport_box vehicles shared_vehicles text-center @if($vehicle_details->is_shared_airport) shared_airport_yes @endif  @if($vehicle_details->is_private_airport) <?php $j++;?> private_airport_yes @endif" style="min-height: 400px;">
    <div class="options__container--option <?= ($i==1 || $j==1 && $vehicle_details->is_private_airport==1)?'checked11':'';?> " >
        <input id="chb1_{{$vehicle_details->id}}"  type="radio"  value="{{$vehicle_details->id}}" name="vehicle_id" data-value="{{$vehicle_details->minimum_hr}} !! {{$vehicle_details->psngr_price_1}} !! {{$vehicle_details->vehicle_name}}" class="shared_airport_box_label <?= ($i==1 || $vehicle_details->is_private_airport==1)?'autochecked':'';?>" >
        <label for="chb1_{{$vehicle_details->id}}" class="shared_airport_box_label">
            
       <img  src="{{ url('core/public/public/Image/'.$vehicle_details->image) }}">
        <h4 class="options__container--title"> {{@$vehicle_details->vehicle_name}}</h4><p> {{ @$vehicle_details->description}}</p>
       
   <p><span style="font-weight: bold;" id="shared_price_{{$vehicle_details->id}}">  </span></p>
   </label>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>



    <?php } 
    
    } ?> </div>            <!-- getsumdivends -->
```

this is my div in which a have stored the session from the controller when i refresh the page i only want  $sum=Session::get('sumofac'); to change not the whole div and
**i then need to use the $sum inside an if case
for eg: if($vehicle_details->maxpassengers >= $sum ) then show the rest of the div below.**

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Wait, you have literal PHP code in a blade view? Use blade syntax, not `<?php` etc... and for you to be able to reload a part of the page, javascript must be used...

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

    public function updateSum(Request $request)
    {
     // Update the session value if needed
     // Session::put('sumofac', $newValue);

    $sum = Session::get('sumofac');

    return response()->json(['sum' => $sum]);
    }



   $(document).ready(function () {
    // Function to update the $sum value without refreshing the div
    function updateSum() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('updateSum') }}",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                // Update the $sum value in your HTML
                var sum = data.sum;
                $("#sumValue").text("sum= " + sum);
 
                if (/* your condition based on $sum */) {
                    $("#restOfDiv").show();
                } else {
                    $("#restOfDiv").hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.error(error);
            },
        });
    }

    // Call the updateSum function initially
    updateSum();

    // You can also call updateSum whenever you need to refresh the $sum value.
    // For example, after some user interactions.

    // Example:
    $("#someButton").click(function () {
        updateSum();
    });
   });
```

Comment: i did this but i can't use this expression  $("#sumValue").text("sum= " + sum); inside an if case of the same div right? @Hilal Ahmad